# Storage Space Error Inaccessible; Reconnect Drives

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, file-recovery, storage-spaces

The storage spaces section in control panel lists "Error Inaccessible; reconnect drives", however each of the physical drives reports a status of "OK":

[image]

Can someone please help me restore the storage space to a working state and recover the data?

My machine got into this state after storage spaces detected that one of my drives was disconnected.  I rebuilt the disconnected drive as requested, it reported success, but 10 minutes later the above happened.

FYI, here are the results of get-virtualdisk and get-storagepool (the full extent of my PS research):

[image]

UPDATE

I ended up "solving" this by restoring everything to a 3rd drive via ReclaiMe, and starting over with a new Storage Spaces drive.

Comment: Well, there's the "I have data in there that I would like to get back." part, but I'm new to superuser, so presumably I worded it poorly. I'll take another stab at it.

Comment: Much better; you describe the problem then ask a question, if software is a solution, then people will naturally suggest something that can accomplish it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trial version of [ReclaiMe Storage Spaces Recovery](http://www.storage-spaces-recovery.com/) can fix some metadata
corruption errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with my two-way mirror recently, only I had yellow warning and could access my data.
I solved it by adding 3rd drive and removing second drive that I knew was bad because of my experiments.

After "Repairing" cycle, my Storage pool became green and happy.

So my advice to you: if you know which drive of those 2 is bad - replace it with another empty drive, like you would if it failed.

If you don't know which one then do this (let's name those drive a and drive b):

1) get new empty drive with at least 600Gb (100Gb larger than smallest drive) size (let's name it drive c)

2) disconnect drive b.

3) connect drive c.

4) wait for "Repairing" cycle to finish

5) if pool is green go to step 20

6) disconnect drive a

7) disconnect drive c

8) get new empty drive with at least 600Gb (100Gb larger than smallest drive) size (let's name it drive d)

9) connect drive b

10) connect drive d

11) wait for "Repairing" cycle to finish

12) if pool is green go to step 20

13) disconnect drive b

14) connect drive c

15) wait for "Repairing" cycle to finish

16) if pool is green go to step 20

17) remember the data loss and never make mirror size bigger than smallest drive size, because you can always increase size of Storage Space and extend size of the Volume that resides on it.

18) goto step 20

19) mark my answer as accepted

20) end of procedure

Comment: :) like, especially #19. Unfortunately, as extremely useful as this information is likely to be for some future poor soul, it wouldn't have helped in my situation. I'm 99% sure I tried this idea. Restoring everything to a 3rd drive via ReclaiMe and starting over was my last resort, but it eventually worked.